# Select every odd element starting at the 5th spot

Tags: css, css-selectors

If I wanted to select every 4th element starting at the 5th spot I would do:

```
.elem:nth-child(4n+5) {
    //something
}
```

But how to do it for every odd element starting at the 5th spot? This syntax doesn't work:

```
.elem:nth-child(:oddn+5) {
    //something
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `.elem:nth-child(2n+5)`

```css
li:nth-child(2n+5) {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ol>
```

The `2n` will select every other element and the `+5` acts as the offset. So with `n` starting at zero, you get 5, 7, 9, 11, ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use

1. `:nth-child(odd)` to select every odd element
2. `:not(:nth-child(-n + 4))` to not select first 4 elements

```css
div:not(:nth-child(-n + 4)):nth-child(odd) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>Div</div><div>Div</div><div>Div</div><div>Div</div><div>Div</div><div>Div</div><div>Div</div><div>Div</div><div>Div</div><div>Div</div>
```

Or if you want to start from 5th element you can change to this

```css
div:not(:nth-child(-n + 5)):nth-child(even) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>Div</div><div>Div</div><div>Div</div><div>Div</div><div>Div</div><div>Div</div><div>Div</div><div>Div</div><div>Div</div><div>Div</div>
```